# Telerik ASP.NET TabStrip client object is not accessible via $find in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer-8, tabs

I am not very familiar with ASP.NET but I have a situation here:

I have a tabbed menu implemented with ASP.NET **C1TabStrip** and **C1MultiPage** controls and I want to have the first tab selected (SelectedIndex="0") on page load in **IE8**.

**NOTE:** I do not have server side access (and I am not familiar in asp.net server side coding)

Here is the code:

```
<cc1:TabStrip ID="TabStrip1" runat="server" MultiPageID="RadMultiPage1" SelectedIndex="0" Skin="MetroTouch" EnableViewState="true" CausesValidation="False" BorderWidth="0">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab ID="TabInformation" runat="server" AccessKey="1" PageViewID="TabInformationPage" BorderWidth="0"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab ID="TabWorkflow" runat="server" AccessKey="2" PageViewID="TabWorkflowPage" BorderWidth="0"></telerik:RadTab>
                <telerik:RadTab ID="TabApproval" runat="server" AccessKey="3" PageViewID="TabApprovalPage" BorderWidth="0"></telerik:RadTab>
            </Tabs>
        </cc1:TabStrip>

<telerik:RadMultiPage ID="RadMultiPage1" runat="server" OnPageViewCreated="RadMultiPage1_PageViewCreated" SelectedIndex="0" EnableViewState="true">

Telerik RadPageView......

</telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

In general it works fine (Chrome, Firefox, IE9 and later), but when the page loads in Internet Explorer 8, no tab is selected by default.

After clicking in one of the tabs, the control works fine.

**Client Side**

I am trying to get the client object with jQuery, using the following script:

```
var tabStrip = $find("<%= TabStrip1.ClientID %>");
var tabStripTab0 = tabStrip.get_tabs().getTab("0");
tabStripTab0.click();
```

In most browsers (Chrome,Firefox,IE9 and later), tabStrip variable gets the ***RadTabStrip object***, but in IE8 it returns **null**

Does anyone have any idea how am I going to get the tabstrip object in IE8?

Thanks in advance!

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I just needed to set a timeout like so:

```
window.onload = tabStripTimeOut;

function tabStripTimeOut() {
        if ($telerik.isIE8) {
            setTimeout(correctTabstripWidth, 500);
        } else {
            correctTabstripWidth();
        }
    }

function correctTabstripWidth() {
    var tabStrip = $find("<%= TabStrip1.ClientID %>");
    var tabStripTab0 = tabStrip.get_tabs().getTab("0");
    tabStripTab0.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have the first tab selected (SelectedIndex="0") **on page load**

If you want it on page load, just do it server side.

Here's an example from http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-set-selected-tab---server-side

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     RadTab tab1 = RadTabStrip1.Tabs.FindTabByText("Tab1");
     tab1.Selected = true;
}
```

In your case there's probably a better and easier way to get access to the tab without searching for it by text, but my WebForms is very rusty ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have access behind (server side), plus I am not familiar with server side asp.net coding. I wander if I could do it client side

Comment: @kapantzak But the `<%= TabStrip1.ClientID %>` in your JS is server side code..? In any case, instead of using `tabStripTab0.click();` you could try `tabStripTab0.select();` http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tabstrip-client-side-basics.html

Comment: The problem is that I cannot get 'tabStrip' in client side. If 'tabStrip' was not null in IE8, I could try select() or click()